# Remove reflection from materials without roughness. Leave reflections on materials with roughness

Tags: lighting, mirror, reflection, roughness

I will give a simple example. There is a glass bottle, a ceramic cup, and a mirror on the table. The bottle and the cup have a low roughness of .07. The mirror has zero roughness.I want to leave all the reflections on the cup and the bottle, but eliminate one directional light source for the mirror. So that the ball doesn't reflect in the mirror. I'm trying to do this in the light source nodes, but it seems you can't use roughness values for masking.

Disabling the visibility of the gloss rays is a bad idea. Because glossy reflections disappear from all objects.
Creating multiple scenes or multiple layers and then trying to combine that in the linker is pretty hard when creating animations. And it takes many times longer. Is there a node-based solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure if this would work, but maybe you could try setting the specular setting to 0. This would remove all glossy reflections from the object, but allow it to still bounce diffused light.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is exactly what you need but disabling `Multiple importance` may remove reflection of light source in cycles.

[image]